# Run release build of iOS app on development device

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4.5

When I build my iPad app for running on my development iPad, it only builds the debug version. I need to see how fast the real release version is; how do I do this? I'm used to Visual Studio's Debug/Release builds, so this Run/Test/Profile/Analyze/Archive stuff isa  bit confusing. I see Schemes are related to this but isn't there a simple switch "I want to test Debug/Release version of my app on my device"?

Comment: I'm very glad I got this working... release version runs 60% faster!

Comment: If you found a solution, please accept an answer that helped you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You want to do a release build using an ad-hoc provisioning profile, which will allow you to install it on your device and any others you have specified.

[Test flight app](https://testflightapp.com) is free and can help with this process as well.

[image: Provisioning Profile]

Comment: This was the key part I wouldn't have figured out - changing to Release alone didn't work as I was using a dev profile.

Comment: Excellent, glad you got it working. If this helped you consider marking it as the answer.

Answer (score 9):

In your scheme settings, you can select to build for debug or release. Make sure you have set up code signing correctly. Xcode 5 can help with that.

Comment: Can you define "correctly"? If it's working for debug won't it work for release? Also... really I have to edit the scheme every time, I can't have separate schemes to test debug/release?

Comment: It is possible to have different schemes, but you can only assign one scheme to the "Run" command. So you'd have to switch the schemes every time. Easier to just change debug/release.

Answer (score 4):

You can create a new `Build Configuration` in the `Project View` under the `Xcode Project`. Make it a duplicate of `Distribution`

[image: New configuration]

Then just choose `Edit Schemes` and choose the new scheme and run on your device. Make sure you the certificates selected in your `Build Settings`. However you don't get full Debugging capabilities when running a `AdHoc`/ `Distribution` build.

Comment: Is this an XCode5-specific thing?

Answer (score 0):

This took me a really long time, but I got it working. I usually use automatic signing and it works great. I switched to using FastLane in order to speed up the test flight distribution process and it required that I switch to manual signing. I had to change my release signing certificate to iOS Distribution.

I then had a bug that was only reproducible in release mode, so I needed to run the app on my device in release mode, but it was a pain to keep re-uploading to test flight.

I tried changing my build system to legacy, but that didn't work. I read up on profiles and certificates and I realized that I need to use iOS development certificates to run on device directly (which is what I was doing in debug mode). However, I needed to use iOS distribution certificates to distribute the app. Automatic signing had been taking care of this for me.

I ended up just turning on automatic signing briefly to test my app and then turned it back off and used git to revert the status of the workspace.

TLDR: turn on automatic signing and then turn it back off when done testing